# Did lord Shiva time travel?

Tags: shiva, time

> Kalinjar means The destroyer of time in Sanskrit. 'Kal' is time and
>   'jar' destruction. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalinjar_Fort#History).

What is meant by `destroyer of time`?

Comment: It has two meanings. Yama dharmaraja is also called Kala. Shiva subdued Yama to preserve Markandeya. So he is kalahantra, Kala kaala etc. Second, because he is paramatma, he is beyond time and space. Therefore, he is Kalijnar for this reason as well.

Comment: see this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8637/why-lord-shiva-is-depicted-as-lord-of-time-kaala

Answer (score 6):

**Kãlãnjãra** means who is the destroyer of Kãla. ie. Who is Kãla of Kãla (Kãlakãla). There is also a tirtha called Kalanjara where Lord Shiva destroyed Kãla while protecting his devotee Sveta. Kurma Purana Uttara Bhaga chapter 36 tells that story:

> There is a **great Tirtha by the name Kãlanjara** which can lead to RudraLoka. Hara is the fond of the devotees who worship lord Kãlãnjãra. In ancient times, a saintly king, **a devotee of Shiva named Sveta,** who with the blessings of Siva, used to adore lord Siva, the bearer of the trident. He, with all the devotion, consecrated the Sivalinga there. Thereafter, he devoting his mind to Shiva, recited the Rudramantra. Thereafter the time of death of the king arrived. In order to lead the king to Yamaloka, the god of death, Kala, arrived, holding a trident in his hand. Then the king Sveta, **finding the god of death in the terrific form**, holding a trident in his hand, was terrified. Then the king touched Shivalinga with both the hands, bowed in reverence before lord Rudra, **reciting the Satarudriya (Sri Rudram) stotra** at the same time. Standing in front of the king, Krtanta (God of Death), laughingly said to the king, who‘ was performing the Japa of Bhava, “You come away, you come away." The king who was devoted to Rudra, getting terrified, **said to Yama, “You leave me since, I am engaged in the worshipping of Shiva,** and carry the other people with you and destroy them. Then, **lord Kala, spoke** to the terrified king. Whether he is engaged in the devotion of Rudra or anyone else, **who is not overpowered by me?”** Thus speaking, **Yama bound the king with his noose, but the king continued to recite the Satarudriya** stotra. Then the **king Sveta, witnessed the great lustre of lord Shiva,** lord of the goblins, adorned with the garlands of flames, which pervaded the entire universe. He witnessed lord Mahadeva. in the lustre adorned with the digit of the moon over the head, illumining at the same time and accompanied by the goddess. The king was immensely pleased by looking at him and realised the arrival of the lord. Finding Rudra, the lord of everything, walking with goddess, at a distance near to him, **the god of death remained unmoved** and tried to carry the great king with him in the presence of lord Shiva. The royal sage became free from fear. Observing this, **Siva, the lord of the living beings, spoke** to the god of death, **“You give away my devotee, who is reciting my name.” The devotee who remembers me, O Kala, he remembers my form.** Listening to the words of lord Shiva, the god of death, because of his nature being horrible, **bound the devotee of Shiva in the noose again** and in anger he rushed towards lord Shiva. Finding the advance of the god of death, **lord Siva,** looked at Parvati, the daughter of the mountain, and **kicked him with his left foot,** while king Sveta was looking on. With the kicking by lord Siva, the awful **Kaladeva was killed** and the Pinaka bearing lord Siva looked graceful with the goddess Uma. The king Sveta felt delighted at the Sight of lord Siva Offering his salutation to Siva, he started eulogising him. He said, “Salutation to Bhava, the cause of the world. Salutation to Hara and the form of welfare for the world. Salutation to the learned Siva, Salutation to the bestower of salvation. Salutation to the one whose body is besmeared with ashes and the possessor of all the fortunes. You have the undivided form, You are lord of the humans, salutation to you. You are the lord of all the Ganas, remover of the pain of those who take refuge in you. Saluation to you. You are without beginning, everlasting, possessor of all the fortunes, and carry the horn of a boar, salutation to you. Salutation to the bull bannered Lord. 0 wearing the garlands of skulls, salutation to you. 0 Great lord of mountain, salutation to you. Salutation to lord Siva, the bestower of welfare **Then lord Sankara, showered his grace on him and bestowed on him the position of Ganapati (chief of his ganas) and the indestructible form of his own.** Then lord Siva with Parvati, accompanied with the king Sveta, having been adored by the Rsis and the Siddhas, disappeared in a moment. At the destruction of the god of death by Siva, **Brahma,** the lord of the lokas, **then asked for a boon from Siva,** “The god of death, **Kala, should be brought back to life.**" Brahma said, “O lshana, Bull bannered God, Krtanta, the god of death, is not at all at any fault, because he has been entrusted with this duty of taking away the life of beings by you yourself.” Listening to the words of Brahma, lord Shiva, the lord of the chief of Devas, said, “Be it so.” **The god of death then got back his life. Therefore this tirtha has been given the name of Kalanjara.** A person who adores lord Siva there, he achieves the position of a Shivagana.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't literally mean "Time Travel" it means he defeated death(In other words- He defeated the time of his death)

> Legend says that after manthan Hindu God, Lord Shiva, drank the poison
>   and his throat became blue (hence the name Neel (blue) Kantha
>   (throat)) and he came to Kalinjar and overcome the 'Kal' i.e. he
>   achieved victory over death.

Source is same "Wiki" [Kalinjar Fort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalinjar_Fort#History)

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: How did shiva achieved victory over death, by destroying time.

Comment: According to me it is a way of saying "He survived by defeating death" it doesn't mean there was a Fight between death and Shiva.

Comment: "He defeated the time of his death" You mean Shiva was about to die? Nice hilarious answer.