# Why Lord Shiva is depicted as Lord of Time?

Tags: shiva, puranas, time, shiva-purana

Kali Mata was named as **Kaali** because she is wife of Lord Shiva, who is said to be Lord of time. As He is Lord of time, few avatars or *Amsas* of Him are named after him such as **KaalaBhairava**. What is Lord Shiva's association with Kaala (Time)?.

Some people say He is **Aajanma** (unborn) and existed before time and thus called Lord of time. If this is true, can anyone validate this by citing a source?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

YajurVeda salutes Lord Shiva by stating:

> नमो अग्रियाय च प्रथमाय च [YajurVeda Taittariya Samhita 4.5.5.2]
>   Namo Agriyaya cha prathamaya cha 
>   **Salutations to Him who was before all things and who is foremost.**

Thus there is no effect of time for Lord Shiva as he was before the time. This is expanded in Taittariya Aranyaka of YajurVeda as:

> वामदेवाय नमो ज्येष्ठाय नमः श्रेष्ठाय नमो **रुद्राय नमः कालाय नमः कलविकरणाय नमो** ।।
>   
>   “vāmadēvāya namō jyēṣṭhāya namaḥ śrēṣṭhāya namō
>   **rudrāya namaḥ kālāya namaḥ kalavikaraṇāya namō** |” (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.18.1)

Here the emphasis is in:

> रुद्राय नमः कालाय नमः कलविकरणाय नमो ।। 
>   rudrāya namaḥ kālāya namaḥ kalavikaraṇāya namō | 
>   Salutations to Rudra. **Salutation to him who is time.** Salutations to him who is the cause of evolution of universe.

Salutations to him who is time/ कालाय नम: is expanded by Shiva Purana as below:

[Chapter 8&9 of Vaayaveeyasamhita Section of Shiva Purana](http://dspace.wbpublibnet.gov.in:8080/jspui/bitstream/10689/12960/5/Chapter3_1733-1812p.pdf) mentions SaakshatShiva as Lord Kaala and time as Energy of Paramesvara.

Sages asked Vayu,

> O skill one, please tell us. Who is this Lord Kaala? Under whose
>   control is he? Who does not come under his control?

Then Vayu said,

> - It is the great splendor of Lord Shiva named **Kaalatman**. **Kalaa, 
>     Kaastha, Nimesha** are the forms it embodies.
> - It is the power of Lord that controls the Universe in the form of directives which are untransgressable to the universe consisting of
>     mobile and immobile beings.
> - The Universe is under the control of Kaala. Kaala is not under the control of Universe. **Kaala is under the control of Shiva. Shiva is
>     not subject to its control.**
> - Since the unobstructed splendor of Shiva is firmly fixed in Kaala the limit of Kaala is extensive and untransgressable.
> - He who thus correctly understands the principle of Kaala goes beyond the time and sees that which is beyond Kaala.
> - Obeisance to **Shiva of wonderful form who has no Kaala to influence him**, no bondage and liberation, is identical neither with
>     Purusha or Prakriti nor the universe.
> - **A day of Brahma's life constitutes life of 14 Indras. A day of Vishnu is life time of Brahma. A day of Rudra is life time of Vishnu. 
>     A day of Shiva is life time of Rudra. A day of SadaaShiva is life
>     period of Shiva. A day of SAAKSHAATSHIVA is life period of
>     SadaaShiva.**
> - **This Kaala functions as directed by Saakshat Shiva**. O Brahmins, this is the period of time of creation as mentioned by me.
> - This Kaalantara shall be known as day of Parameswara. Parameswara's night shall be known to extend so long.
> - His day is period of creation. His night is period of dissolution. But understand he has neither day or night as we conceive them.
> - The dissolution is effected for the benefits of the world. The subjects, the Prajapathis, the three deities, Gods, Asuras, the sense
>     organs, the sensual objects, the five great elements, the subtle and
>     gross elements, the cosmic intellect, the deities, all these abide during
>     the day of Paramesvara. They get dissolved at end of the day. At the
>     end of night again begins the origin of universe.
> - Obeisance to the great Shiva, the soul of the universe, whose energy in respect of activity, time, innate nature is untransgressable
>     and under whose command the whole universe functions.

Comment: Good answer.  I just posted a question related to the "Sakshat Shiva" figure mentioned in this chapter: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9291/36

Comment: How much is a day of Rudra? Just like Brahma life period is 100 years.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria The Shiva Purana says that the lifetime of Rudra is 100 years of Rudra, 1 day of Rudra is 100 years of Vishnu, and 1 day of Vishnu is 100 years of Brahma.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: What Sri Vishnu Puranam and other Puranams says about life time of `Lord Sri Maha Vishnu`. Lifetime of Sri Maha Vishnu swarupa is 100 years of Rudra ??