# Questions about Origins and the Apocalypse

Tags: belief, philosophy

I have a school assignment on Origins and Apocalyptic tales. I would like to understand your beliefs on how the world was created and how it will end and have created the following questions to help me do so. I would appreciate it if you were able to answer them. Please answer in as much depth as possible and if you have any queries feel free to ask them to clear it up. Thank you! 
Long responses are fine :)
This is different from another question as it is an ethnographic study with precise questions to understand in depth what people's beliefs (or experiences) may be.

What is your belief on how the world and human life was created and how does it, if at all, differ from your friends or family?
Is this belief shared across your entire religion or does it differ with denominations?
Does this belief have any significance to you? Does it impact your day to day life or how you live it?

What is your belief on how the world will end, aka the “apocalypse”, and how does it differ, if at all, from your friends or family?
Is this belief shared across your entire religion or does it differ with denominations?
Does this belief have any significance to you? Does it impact your day to day life or how you live it?

Where did these beliefs come from?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! See these questions for How Universe was created and how three important gods in Hinduism were born.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8508/3500 and http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/237/3500.

Comment: In short, Brahman ( everything is Brahman. You,me .rock , neutron, Physical Universe,Spirutual Universe and everything we see,perceive and that which we cannot perceive, is Brahman) has 2 forms Manifest(Suguna) and Unmanifest.(Nirguna). Nirguna has no attributes( can be considered as singularity). Suguna Brahman has all attributes . At the time of dissolution, manifest mingles with unmanifest and there is nothingness. After same time, manifest forms from unmanifest and creation starts. This is never ending cyclic process with no beginning.

Comment: Time has no beginning and ending. The Brahman( Parameswara for Shaivaites) is beyond time and human perception. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9290/3500 . Brahman is one (Advaita ). Vaishnavaites consider Brahman as Vishnu whereas Shaivaites consider Brahman as Shiva. Name only changes but Brahman is one. Vedas, as time, are eternal. They give this cosmic knowledge. Puranas are history books of major events since eternal. They describe various events of this cosmos.

Comment: The divine sound ॐ (AUM/OM) signifies creation,Preservation and destruction.ॐdenotes Supreme Brahman. These three activities are done by Brahma, Vishnu and Shankara(Rudra) respectively. These three deities are different aspects of Supreme Brahman.

Comment: There is no apocalypse in Hinduism. There is no final judgement as in Christian beliefs. ALL souls will eventually go to God, some go faster and some go slower, but no one is condemned for eternity - there is no devil in Hinduism. There have been innumerable universes before and innumerable universes in the future. See the questions referred to in Anil Kumar's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the text, Yoga Vashishtha, it answers these questions:

> Regarding creation and dissolution:
>
> The one pure consciousness appears as the diverse dream-objects in a
>   dream. All these millions of objects which appear in the dream become
>   one again in deep sleep. Similarly, when this dream-world appears in
>   the infinite consciousness that itself is called creation; when this
>   itself enters into the equivalent of the deep sleep state, it is known
>   as the cosmic dissolution. This is pure commonsense. (VI.2:143)
>
> Regarding difference in identity: All these universes are but its
>   playful but conscious projection. As the diversity of this universe,
>   it seems to be divided in itself; but truly, it is undivided.

Here is the link:
http://yogi.lv/files/yoga_vasistha.pdf

Regarding belief:
I cannot speak for other people. Although, I have meditated for 6 years and I experience this 'energy field' around me. So, the question should be regarding 'experience' and not 'belief'. I do know a lot of meditators across the world with similar experiences.

Once, I know that this same energy might be ever-present, then the smaller identifications of race, caste etc disappear. That is how it affects me personally.

I hope this helped! :)