# What is the Hindu view of time?

Tags: time

I understand time doesn't always move forward linearly in the Hindu view.  Can someone give a clear explanation of Yugas,Kalpas etc. and how time moves in cycles?

This purpose of this question is to understand what "beginning" and "end" mean in Hindu cosmogony.  Are there many beginnings and many endings of time?

Comment: Sorry didn’t get exactly what you’re saying. You want to know how satya yuga comes after kali and the yuga cycles repeat? Or anything additionally as well? Basically something like a concise thing not as elaborate as the Puranas correct?

Comment: the Western cultural view is linear only - time doesn't cycle.  "the moving finger writes, and having writ, moves on".  the western scientific view is either big bang or steady state.  I'd like to contrast the Hindu view with that @archit - at a high level.

Comment: [Video related](https://youtu.be/UUrmeI6wn2o)

Comment: Related or Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12518/in-hinduism-how-has-kala-or-time-been-described

Comment: voila!! @proxy.  it is impossible to conceive of yugas cycling without an underlying linear time beneath the "cycles".

Comment: Time always moves forward, but the yugas, kalpas, etc are just repeating. That doesn't mean you're going back in time, it means time is still going forward linearly, but the ages of mankind repeat (not as it already happened).

Comment: so creation pralaya creation pralaya ......and so forth is still embedded in linear time?  that means creation-pralaya cycles can be ordered with respect to the forward arrow of time?  does the next creation cycle "remember" everything from the previous cycle? @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SK Yes, yes, and if I understand you correctly, yes. The events of the previous cycle still happened; only a new cycle begins.

Comment: So Ramayana,Mahabharata etc happen infinitely often, moving forward in linear time, but with slight variations each time? @ Ikshvaku

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who is kaal? What is kaal?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/who-is-kaal-what-is-kaal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the duration (Timeline) of the four "Yugas"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas)